# postgresqlでhstore型を使用したい

Tags: sql, postgresql

環境
CentOS リリース 6.8
contrib...yumでインストールしたが、pgsqlの中にcontribというフォルダが作成されない。
psqlコマンドを打つと、psql (8.4.xx, サーバ 9.1.xx)と出てくる。
postgresqlのバージョンはおそらく9.1？

言い忘れてましたが、データベースクラスタを2つ作成して、postgresを2つ使えるようにしています。portを変更して

postgresqlでhstoreを使用したいと思っています。
yumでhstore.controlが入っていると思われる、yum install postgresql-contrib.x86_64を入れました。
再度hstore型を有効する為に、
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;をしても
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/path/extension/hstore.control": ENOENT
と言われて、ファイルがありませんと言われます。

実際にファイルを確認したら、ありませんでした。
ご指導お願いします。

どこか足りない所がありますか？
hstoreのデータがないように見えます・・・
インストールは上手くいったようなのに・・・

================================================
結果
結果ですが、psqlのバージョンが8.4から9.1にしたようでその9.1のデータがのパスが違ったようでした。
前のpsqlを削除して、その後にhstore型をインストール出来てうまく動いて、問題なくhstore型が動くようになり、万事解決しました。
皆さんありがとうございました。

Comment: OSはなんんでしょうか。本体とcontribのインストール元のリポジトリはそれぞれどこでしょうか。8.4.20というのは何のバージョンですか？質問を編集して詳細を追記してください

Answer (score 1):

CentOS6.8であれば、CentOSのyumリポジトリからインストールされるPostgreSQL(contrib含む)のバージョンは`8.4.20`になると思います。
`9.1.x`は別の方法でインストールされたと予想しますので、`postgresql-contrib`も同様の方法でインストールすることで`hstore`EXTENSIONが利用可能になると思います。

＃[PostgreSQLのyumリポジトリ](https://yum.postgresql.org/)からインストールしたのであれば、`postgresql91-contrib`とバージョン名つきのRPM名になっていると思います。